# How do I install maven plugin into an existing project?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

Is there a proper way of doing this maybe through a command line? Or do I really have to modify the POM file itself? Let's say I want to install the maven war plugin into an existing project. I tried googling but I can only find the usage and not the installation to an existing project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html),

> Maven is - at its heart - a plugin execution framework; all work is
>   done by plugins.

You must mean invoking or using a plugin than *installing a plugin*.  You can invoke pretty much any maven plugin without updating the pom, so long as you are ok with the default configurations.

For instance, to generate a javadoc on a maven project, you could just type

```
mvn javadoc:javadoc
```

Now, coming to `maven war plugin`.  This creates a `war` artifact of your project. It makes no sense to invoke it on a project, unless the project is a `war` project.  If it is so, the `packaging` of the project should be `war`.

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

In this case, maven war plugin gets automatically invoked on it.

If you want to customize/configure a plugin or based on the type of plugin, you declare it in your pom (in `<plugins>` section and do the configurations).

Comment: Thanks for giving me an idea. So that means a plugin gets associated to a project if I have some customization right? I thought plugins such as maven war plugin get installed to a project by either editing the POM or invoking a command line or something else.

Comment: @supertonsky. Updated answer with a little more info.  Essentially, `plugins` operate on your project, and perform desired operations.

Comment: Good answer. Essential Maven is a thin boot strap. Everything gets downloaded and installed into the local repository, based on the plug-ins used by the build.

Answer (score 2):

You add the plugin to the POM.

Maven configuration is done via the POM; it's kind of the point--the POM defines the project.

Comment: Do you mean the only way of doing this is editing the POM file by hand?

Comment: @DNn I don't know that's why I'm asking. I'm just making sure you're addressing my question and that I understand your answer. I was guessing that maybe there's a command line that would install the plugin and update the POM file. I don't even know why do we need plugins inside the POM file I thought it's something that is not associated to any projects but I'm seeing some plugins declared inside the POM file.

Comment: @DᴀᴠᴇNᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ - some people are very clever with their feet.  :-)

Comment: @supertonsky - the project's POM is a file.  You open it in a text editor and edit it to add plugin descriptors for the plugins your project's build uses.  That's how you tell Maven which plugins to use when building the project.  It sounds like you need to read or reread this: http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html